# How can I copy all links displays in all opened webpages (tabs)?

Tags: google-chrome, links

How can I copy all links displays in all the webpages I have opened in Chrome (I can use another browser if needed). Please note that I don't want to copy the urls of the tabs themselves, but the urls that are shown as links within each of the opened tabs.

Comment: there are extensions that do exactly that. You make a selection, and it can then copy or open those links

Comment: What selection do I make Sir? I am talking about all the links from all opened webpages, there is no way to make a selection. Which extension do you refer to, because I tried many and they either copy the urls of the tabs or the links of the current only webpage.

Comment: it seems you already tried one of the extensions I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Firefox extension
[Easy Copy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-copy/?src=cb-dl-hotness)
has this ability, when using its option of
[Copy All Tabs](https://sites.google.com/site/smokyinkproductions/easy-copy/options#TOC-Copy-All-Tabs-since-v2.0.0-),
but I cannot test it. You will find a description of the extension in the article
[How to Copy Multiple URLs with One Click in Firefox](https://www.maketecheasier.com/copy-multiple-urls-firefox/).

Unfortunately this extension is of a format incompatible with the latest
Firefox Quantum version.
You will need to use a Firefox fork that still supports this format, for example
[Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/).

I am going here strictly by the documentation, so cannot guarantee the
suitability of this extension.